# Silverlight WCF data service call back returns on UI thread

Tags: multithreading, silverlight, mvvm, wcf-data-services, silverlight-5.0

I am using `Silverlight 5` with `WCF data service` and I have installed Silverlight WCF data Service client library.

Ideally, When I execute `DataServiceQuery<T>.BeginExecute`, call back should return on worker thread but in my case It returns on UI thread.

Why it concerns me is my payload is very huge and it takes somewhere around 6-7 seconds to materialize response to objects (`DataServiceQuery<T>.EndExecute method`). So if it is running on UI thread it blocks my UI for 6-7 seconds.

How can I get response on worker thread, materialize response on worker thread and then switch to UI thread to update my UI.

Does anyone has faced similar problem?

This is my code.

```
private void getRealTimeAssetProfileQuery(Guid assetProfileID, DateTime fromDate, DateTime toDate)
{
    dateRanges[assetProfileID].Add(new Range<DateTime>(fromDate, toDate));

    context = ServiceAgent.Context;
    var qry = (from o in context.RealTimeProfilePoint
               where o.ProfileID == assetProfileID && o.PointTime >= fromDate && o.PointTime <= toDate
               orderby o.PointTime descending
               select o) as DataServiceQuery<RealTimeProfilePoint>;

    qry = qry.AddQueryOption("$expand", "Profile");
    qry = qry.AddQueryOption("$expand", "Profile/ProfileType");


    dynamic asyncState = new
    {
        assetProfileID = assetProfileID,
        fromDate = fromDate,
        toDate = toDate
    };


    Uri qryUri = new Uri(qry.ToString());

    context.BeginExecute<RealTimeProfilePoint>(qryUri, new AsyncCallback(realTimeCallBack), asyncState);
}

void realTimeCallBack(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
{
    if (Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.CheckAccess())
        raiseTrace("Data Service Response On UI Thread \n");
    else
        raiseTrace("Data Service Response On worker Thread \n");


    dynamic asyncState = asyncResult.AsyncState as dynamic;

    Guid assetProfileID = asyncState.assetProfileID;
    DateTime fromDate = asyncState.fromDate;
    DateTime toDate = asyncState.toDate;

    IEnumerable<RealTimeProfilePoint> profilePoints = context.EndExecute<RealTimeProfilePoint>(asyncResult);

    List<RealTimeProfilePoint> lstProfilePoint = profilePoints.ToList();

    if (((QueryOperationResponse)profilePoints).GetContinuation() != null)
    {
        Uri qryUri = ((QueryOperationResponse)profilePoints).GetContinuation().NextLinkUri;

        context.BeginExecute<RealTimeProfilePoint>(qryUri, new AsyncCallback(realTimeCallBack), asyncState);
    }

    if (lstProfilePoint.Count > 0)
    {
        var assetProfile = lstProfilePoint[0].Profile;

        Instance.addRealTimePoints(assetProfile, lstProfilePoint);

        raiseTrace(
               "Fetching Real Time Profile Points from Server for AssetProfileID " +
               assetProfileID.ToString() + " : " +
               lstProfilePoint.Count.ToString() + " record(s) found for" +
               fromDate.ToUtcTime().ToString() + " - " + toDate.ToUtcTime().ToString() +
               " peiod.");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Start your request from a (background) thread.

```
 dynamic asyncState = new
 {
     assetProfileID = assetProfileID,
     fromDate = fromDate,
     toDate = toDate,

     uiDispatcher = Application.Current.MainWindow.Dispatcher, // for gui access on background thread
 };

 new Thread(() =>
 {
     context.BeginExecute<RealTimeProfilePoint>(qryUri, new AsyncCallback(realTimeCallBack), asyncState);
 })
 {
     IsBackground = true,
 }
 .Start();
```